# How to create a menu of tree items by KnpMenu in symfony2

Tags: symfony, menu, knpmenu

I'd like to create a ul like following:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a><a>
       <ul>......</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The sub ul would be another sub item, I have no idea how to create it, any one could help me thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$menu = $factory->createItem('root');

$menu
    ->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav pull-right');

$menu
    ->addChild('User')
    ->setAttribute('dropdown', true);

$menu['User']
    ->addChild('Profile', array(
        'uri' => '#'
    ))
    ->setAttribute('divider_append', true);

$menu['User']
    ->addChild('Logout', array(
        'uri' => '#'
    ));
```

More information: http://linkofy.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/using-knpmenubundle-and-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: thanks, thats the answer what I want (included link), and sry for my reputation to vote you up :(

Comment: I suggest using getter method for child retrieval:
$menu->getChild('User');  This way you will get autocomplete (@return ItemInterface)  in IDE and you won't break encapsulation OOP concept.